# How to get continuous vertical line without breaking inside array environment?

Tags: arrays, booktabs, cline

I am facing a problem in the following code, i found that there is a breaking in two vertical lines as shown in red mark when i used the command `\cmidrule[1pt](r{-1.0em}){1-4}` inside array environment, i want it to be continuous vertical lines without affecting the length the of horizontal line from s to s
Here is MWE which i have tried so far

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}

   \begin{document}

   $
   \left\{\begin{array}{llllllll|llllll|llllllll}
   s&&:$-$&&\hspace{-2mm}|s&\hspace{-7mm}.,m&\hspace{-2mm}:s&\hspace{-3mm}.,d^{1}&t_{1}&&\hspace{-2mm}:$-$&&\hspace{-3mm}|t_{1}&\hspace{-5mm}:~~&f&&\hspace{-3mm}:$-$&&\hspace{-2mm}|f&\hspace{-5mm}.,r&\hspace{-2mm}:f&\hspace{-2mm}.,l\\ \cmidrule[1pt](r{-1.0em}){1-4}
   m&\hspace{-2mm}.m&:m&\hspace{-2mm}.,m&\hspace{-2mm}|m&&\hspace{-2mm}:s&\hspace{-3mm}.,d^{1}&f&\hspace{-3mm}.f&\hspace{-2mm}:f&\hspace{-3mm}.,f&\hspace{-3mm}|f&\hspace{-5mm}:~~&r&\hspace{-2mm}.r&\hspace{-3mm}:r&\hspace{-2mm}.,r&\hspace{-2mm}|r&&\hspace{-2mm}:f&\hspace{-2mm}.,l\\
   &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
   Whit&&$-$&&&\hspace{-5mm}er&\hspace{-2mm}than&\hspace{-2mm}the&snow,&&&&&&Whit&&\hspace{-3mm}$-$&&&\hspace{-4mm}er&\hspace{-2mm}than&\hspace{-2mm}the\\
   Whit&\hspace{-2.5mm}$-$~er&than&\hspace{-2mm}the&\hspace{-2mm}snow,&&&&whit&\hspace{-4mm}$-$~er&\hspace{-2mm}than&\hspace{-2mm}the&\hspace{-3mm}snow,&&Whit&\hspace{-3mm}$-$~er&\hspace{-2mm}than&\hspace{-2mm}the&snow,&&&\\
   &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
   d^{1}&\hspace{-2mm}.d^{1}&:d^{1}&\hspace{-2mm}.,d^{1}&\hspace{-2mm}|d^{1}&&\hspace{-2mm}:&&r^{1}&\hspace{-3mm}.r^{1}&\hspace{-2mm}:r^{1}&\hspace{-2mm}.,r^{1}&\hspace{-3mm}|r^{1}&\hspace{-5mm}:~~&t&\hspace{-2mm}.t&\hspace{-3mm}:t&\hspace{-2mm}.,t&\hspace{-2mm}|t&&\hspace{-2mm}:&\\
   d&\hspace{-2mm}.d&:d&\hspace{-2mm}.,d&\hspace{-2mm}|d&&\hspace{-2mm}:&&s_{1}&\hspace{-3mm}.s_{1}&\hspace{-2mm}:s_{1}&\hspace{-2mm}.,s_{1}&\hspace{-3mm}|s_{1}&\hspace{-5mm}:~~&s&\hspace{-2mm}.s&\hspace{-3mm}:s&\hspace{-2mm}.,s&\hspace{-2mm}|s&&\hspace{-2mm}:&\\
   \end{array}\right\}
   $
   \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Horizontal rules from the `booktabs` package are incompatible with vertial lines. You could use `\cline` insead of the `\cmidrule`. Maybe an `array` is not the best environment for the output you want to achieve.

Comment: but `\cline` will affect the length of horizontal lines, if `\cline` can be made as desire length then this could be solved my problem @leandriis

Comment: This is correct. Apart from that, could you please give a reason for all the `\hspace` commands. I am quite sure that one can achieve the desired alignment without all thouse manual corrections, so maybe you don't need to manually correct the length of `\cline` either.

Comment: i used `\hspace` because unwanted space are created and also at the same time i have to filled all the texts inside the page, if i don't use `\hspace` then the text will go outside of my document. @leandriis

Comment: Could you pease also explain if the text is somehow aligned with respect to the contents in the upper and lower rows? So is there any connection between the position of the word `than` with the position of `:-` and `:d1`?

Comment: To reduce the horizontal white space around columns, you can use `\setlength{\arraycolsep}{4pt}` or any other length of your choice (default is 6pt). Also, the usage of `|` for vertical lines is not correct. If you want vertical lines only for some columns, you can use `\multicolumn{l|}{...}` for a left aligned column with a vertical line on the right side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see if the following simple solution gives result which can be acceptable to you:

- use simple `\cline` instead `\cmidrule`
- remove all `\hspace{- ...}` (it purpose is unclear),
- reduce column horizontal spacing by `\setlength\arraycolsep{1.5pt}`

  ```
  \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
  \usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
  \usepackage{booktabs}

     \begin{document}

     $\setlength\arraycolsep{1.5pt}
     \left\{\begin{array}{ll ll ll ll|llllll|llllllll}
  s &&:$-$&&|s&.,m&:s&.,d^{1}&t_{1} &&:$-$&&|t_{1}&:&f&&:$-$&&|f&.,r&:f&.,l \\ \cline{1-5}
  m & .m&:m& .,m& |m&& :s& .,d^{1}&f& .f& :f& .,f& |f& :&r& .r& :r& .,r& |r&& :f& .,l\\[2ex]
  %
  Whit&&$-$&&& er& than& the&snow,&&&&&&Whit&& $-$&&& er& than& the\\
  Whit&$-$~er&than&the&snow,&&&&whit&$-$~er&than&the&snow,&&Whit&$-$~er&than&the&snow,&&&\\[2ex]
  %
  d^{1}&.d^{1}&:d^{1}&.,d^{1}&|d^{1}&&:&&r^{1}&.r^{1}&:r^{1}&.,r^{1}&|r^{1}&: &t&.t&:t&.,t&|t&&:&\\
  d&.d&:d&.,d&|d&&:&&s_{1}&.s_{1}&:s_{1}&.,s_{1}&|s_{1}&:&s&.s&:s&.,s&|s&&:&\\
     \end{array}\right\}
     $
     \end{document}
  ```

result of above *mwe* is:

[image]

addendum: regarding your comment, i see two possible solution:

- one use solution with `cmidrule` as is done in @Bernard answer
- draw this line with help of `tikzmark` library:

  - remove `cline` from the array code
  - in preamble add

    ```
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
    ```
  - change the first row in the array to

    ```
    \tikzmarknode{a}{s} &&:$-$&&|\tikzmarknode{b}{s}&.,m&:s&.,d^{1}&t_{1} &&:$-$&&|t_{1}&:&f&&:$-$&&|f&.,r&:f&.,l \\
    ```

    m & .m&:m& .,m& |m&& :s& .,d^{1}&f& .f& :f& .,f& |f& :&r& .r& :r& .,r& |r&& :f& .,l\[2ex]
  - after array add

    ```
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture,transform canvas={yshift=-0.75ex}]
         {\draw (a.south west) -- (b.south east);}
    ```
  - using this solution you can simply make line in different color, appearance (with use TikZ library `decorations.pathmorphing`), etc (if this doesn't matter :-) ) and probably more important, you not need to adjust length of this line.
  - result after (needed) two compilation is:

[image]

Comment: How to reduce the length of horizontal line that is extended the right side of `s `towards `.,m` @Zarko

Comment: one way is to use solution showed in @Bernard answer, i.e. combining both answer. for other possible solution i need more time to check out.

Comment: no shape name (a) is known @Zarko

Answer (score 2):

The lines of `booktabs` have some padding above and below them. So we can change their values, and compensate this padding using `\bigstrut` in well chosen cells.

This being said, as I don't understand the exact layout  you're trying to achieve, and the reason of all those `\hspaces`, I can't propose any simpler solution.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell, bigstrut}
\usepackage{amsmath}

   \begin{document}

   $ \setlength{\aboverulesep}{-1pt} \setlength{\belowrulesep}{-1pt}
   \left\{\begin{array}{*{8}{l}|*{6}{l}|*{8}{l}}
 \bigstrut[b] s & & :$-$ & & \hspace{-2mm}| s & \hspace{-7mm}.,m & \hspace{-2mm}:s & \hspace{-3mm}.,d^{1} & t_{1} & & \hspace{-2mm}:$-$ & & \hspace{-3mm}|t_{1} & \hspace{-5mm}:~~ & f & & \hspace{-3mm}:$-$ & & \hspace{-2mm}|f & \hspace{-5mm}.,r & \hspace{-2mm}:f & \hspace{-2mm}., \\
   \cmidrule[1pt](r{-1.0em}){1-4}
  \bigstrut[t] m & \hspace{-2mm}.m & :m & \hspace{-2mm}.,m & \hspace{-2mm}|m & & \hspace{-2mm}:s & \hspace{-3mm}.,d^{1} & f & \hspace{-3mm}.f & \hspace{-2mm}:f & \hspace{-3mm}.,f & \hspace{-3mm}|f & \hspace{-5mm}:~~ & r & \hspace{-2mm}.r & \hspace{-3mm}:r & \hspace{-2mm}.,r & \hspace{-2mm}|r & & \hspace{-2mm}:f & \hspace{-2mm}.,l \\
    & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
   \text{Whit} & & $-$ & & & \hspace{-5mm}\text{er} & \hspace{-2mm}\text{than} & \hspace{-2mm}\text{the} & \text{snow,} & & & & & & \text{Whit} & & \hspace{-3mm}$-$ & & & \hspace{-4mm}\text{er} & \hspace{-2mm}\text{than} & \hspace{-2mm}\text{the}\\
   \text{Whit} & \hspace{-2.5mm}$-$~\text{er} & \text{than} & \hspace{-2mm}\text{the} & \hspace{-2mm}\text{snow,} & & & & \text{whit} & \hspace{-4mm}$-$~\text{er} & \hspace{-2mm}\text{than} & \hspace{-2mm}\text{the} & \hspace{-3mm}\text{snow,} & & \text{Whit} & \hspace{-3mm}$-$~\text{er} & \hspace{-2mm}\text{than} & \hspace{-2mm}\text{the} & \text{snow,} & & & \\
    & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
   d^{1} & \hspace{-2mm}.d^{1} & :d^{1} & \hspace{-2mm}.,d^{1} & \hspace{-2mm}|d^{1} & & \hspace{-2mm}: & & r^{1} & \hspace{-3mm}.r^{1} & \hspace{-2mm}:r^{1} & \hspace{-2mm}.,r^{1} & \hspace{-3mm}|r^{1} & \hspace{-5mm}:~~ & t & \hspace{-2mm}.t & \hspace{-3mm}:t & \hspace{-2mm}.,t & \hspace{-2mm}|t & & \hspace{-2mm}: & \\
   d & \hspace{-2mm}.d & :d & \hspace{-2mm}.,d & \hspace{-2mm}|d & & \hspace{-2mm}: & & s_{1} & \hspace{-3mm}.s_{1} & \hspace{-2mm}:s_{1} & \hspace{-2mm}.,s_{1} & \hspace{-3mm}|s_{1} & \hspace{-5mm}:~~ & s & \hspace{-2mm}.s & \hspace{-3mm}:s & \hspace{-2mm}.,s & \hspace{-2mm}|s & & \hspace{-2mm}: & \\
   \end{array}\right\}
   $

   \end{document}
```

[image]